# Inserting enclosed Street Names into street_name column of polygon in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a set of polygons in a feature class & there are streets layer with names within these polygons as shown in the attached image.

How to insert the enclosed Street Names into the **street_name** column of a polygon in ArcGIS for Desktop?

[image]

Comment: make your streets into polygon (use small buffer) then you can dissolve them, FME can do this as well https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/23304/dissolving-features-using-the-dissolver-transforme.html

Answer (score 1):

There are many options here. The easiest would probably be to use the [intersect tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm) to intersect your street and polygon layers. The resulting table would have the info you need. You'd have to either **A**) use [calculate field](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm) to get all of the streets as a list in a single field, or **B**) copy the table to an excel file and use a pivot table or some such device.

Or... if you're familiar with arcpy, you can select features in your roads layer that intersect your polygon layer, use a search cursor to build a list of street names from that selection, and then update a field in your polygon layer with that list.

Answer (score 1):

The most critical issue here is to know the length of the Street_Names field, since some of your polygons may have hundreds of intersecting lines and concatenating all street name may require a large TEXT field. If you approximately know or guess this size, [Spatial Join](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) is the way to go. You need to use Field Map of Join Feature parameter as explained in [here](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/12/04/spatialjoinfieldmap/).

Comment: I have a maximum of 11 street names only in a polygon.

Comment: Then, as in the example of esri blog, you can create a new TEXT field in the field map with a size of [Total_Number_Of_Characters_In_11_Streets_Once_They_Are_Concatenated]+10 (the number of delimiters, say comma as in your example). After that you need to select street name field from your line feature class and define it as Input Field.